# Question on gcd, is this true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+},\ a<b,\ d=\gcd(a,b)\ $ and $\ 1<d<a,\ x=\frac ad,\ y=\frac bd,\ x,y \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

Suppose $a=a_1+a_2,\ b=b_1+b_2,\ a_1<b_1,\ d_1=\gcd(a_1,b_1)$ and $1<d_1<a_1,$

if $\frac{a_1}{d_1}=x\ $ and $\ \frac{b_1}{d_1}=y,\ $ then $\ \gcd(a_2,b_2)=d-d_1$.

It seems this question is very simple,but I dont know if this question is right(include  grammar etc.).Could there's a proof for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: You have $$a=xd,\; b=yd,\; a_1=x d_1,\; b_1=y d_1$$ 
and therefore
$$a_2=x(d-d_1), \quad b_2=y(d-d_1)$$
So $d-d_1$ is a common divisor of $a_2$ and $b_2$. What you know about $\gcd(x,y)$?

Comment: @gammatester,Thanks!Maybe $gcd(x,y)=1$.

Comment: @miket: Yes, $g=\gcd(x,y)=1,\,$ otherwise $g\cdot d\,$ would be a common divisor of $a\,$ and $b\,$ greater than $d$.

Comment: @gammatester ,Your cool and atractive answer I like.How about this question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791311/relationship-between-two-elements-of-two-matrices-with-two-numbers-are-not-eleme at least one number not in the two matrices can be strictly proved,and for two numbers there's a unreadable proof,maybe there's shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\ \ && \ \ (a,b) &=& \ \ (d\,x,d\,y),\ \ {\rm where}\ \  d = \gcd(a,b),\ \ {\rm so}\ \ \color{#c00}{\gcd(x,y)= 1}\\
&& (a_1,b_1) &=& (d_1 x,d_1 y) \\
&& (a_2,b_2) &=& (a,b) - (a_1,b_1)\\
&&           &=& (d_2 x,d_2 y),\ \ {\rm for}\,\ \  d_2 = d - d_1\\
\Rightarrow\ \ \ \ \ &&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \gcd\!\!(a_2,b_2) &=& \gcd\!\!(d_2 x, d_2 y) = d_2\color{#c00}{\gcd(x,y)} = d_2
\end{eqnarray}$